# Finding the center of mass of a 1 dimensional rod with varying denisty

Tags: integration

Determine the center of mass of a one dimensional rod bar length of L meters with variable mass density distribution $f(x)=1+2x$

So I know that if the density is constant I just need to multiply the area  by the density however here we have varying density so my intuition is adding the density at each point then multiplying . But I am not sure what to integrate the density relative too in this case

Answer (score 2):

You are given mass density distribution $f(x)=1+2x$ and the length of the rod is $L$.

So, the required mass is $$M=\int_0^L1+2x\ dx$$

Comment: Wouldn't that give us the total mass though not the center of it?